# UIRefreshControl Stuck After Switching Tabs in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, refresh, uirefreshcontrol

I have a UITableViewController as the root view controller in a UINavigationController, which is in turn one of the view controllers in a UITabBarController. All hooked up in Storyboard.

I've configured the UIRefreshControl for my table in Storyboard as well, and normally it looks like it should when pulling:

[image: Normal UIRefreshControl]

However, if I switch between my other tabs once or twice, it looks like this:

[image: Buggy UIRefreshControl]

It's not spinning or anything, just stuck "full", and it stays that way until I pull fully and trigger a refresh.

Any ideas or suggestions appreciate.

Comment: May be it is a bug in ios itself?

Comment: Too many solutions that not working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know this is incredibly late, but I figure better late than never.

Unfortunately, none of the given answers worked for me. The only thing that worked was this awful piece of code in viewWillAppear:

```
self.refreshControl = nil;
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshFunction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
```

Basically I recreate the UIRefreshControl every time the view is going to appear. It works, albeit while giving the following warning:

> Attempting to change the refresh control while it is not idle is
>   strongly discouraged and probably won't work properly.

I'm honestly surprised this is still an issue (still seeing this in iOS 9 now). Hopefully this may be helpful to some other people.

Comment: Great Answer! I still see this issue in iOS 9. This need to be solved by Apple in their next release.

Comment: Same for me. I see it now in my app. iOS 10.2 (14C89).

Comment: Stil the only proper solution for iOS 12.2. For those considering simply calling "endRefreshing" upon viewDidAppear or other, change tabs/views fairly quickly and that is why those solutions do not work.

Answer (score 13):

user2009606 was almost right, I fixed it by calling

```
[refreshControl endRefreshing];
```

On

```
viewWillAppear:
```

The refreshControl now behaves properly after switching tabs, independent of its state.

Answer (score 6):

To sum up and provide a complete solution.

The problem:

If UIRefreshControl is animating during screen transition, it will stay visible but will not be animating. Video https://vid.me/Bkb7

Also, if pull to refresh animation was started but not completed, and then transition was performed, UIRefreshControl will be hidden but stuck. Video https://vid.me/Bkb7

Solution:

Start UIRefreshControl animation on viewWillAppear and end it on viewDidDisappear. Save the state of refresh process to know when to show UIRefreshControl.

Bellow is the whole solution that also handles the proper animation and simple pull to refresh animation.

Add to UITableView or subclass

Initialization:

```
 /// Refresh indicator
var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

/// Refresh state
var isRefreshing = false

/// Refresh controll update funcion. Set to enable pull to refresh
var refreshControllUpdateFunction: (() -> ())?

/// Prepeares UIRefreshControll. Call from init
func initRefreshControl(){
    addSubview(refreshControl)

    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refreshControllTarget", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    refreshControl.beginRefreshing()

    isRefreshing = true
}
```

Superview event handlers:

```
/// Call on viewWillApper
func superviewWillApper(){
    if isRefreshing && !refreshControl.refreshing{
        startRefreshAnimation()
    }
}

/// Call on viewDidDisapper
func superviewDidDisappear(){
    endRefreshAnimation(false, dataFetched: !isRefreshing)
}
```

UIRefreshControl animation handler:

```
/// Presents animating UIRefreshControll
func startRefreshAnimation(){
    refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
    contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -refreshControl.bounds.size.height)

    isRefreshing = true
}

/// Hides UIRefreshControll and saves state of refresh
func endRefreshAnimation(wasEmpty: Bool, dataFetched: Bool){
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()

    isRefreshing = !dataFetched

    if !wasEmpty{
        setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: true)
    }else{
        setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Add

```
table.isRefreshing = true
```

to begining of the refresh call.

Result video https://vid.me/LyuI

Answer (score 4):

The following solution may help you.

```
CGFloat yTableViewOffset;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

      yTableViewOffset = kNilOptions;
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   if(yTableViewOffset != kNilOptions) {

     CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(tableView.contentOffset.x, yTableViewOffset);
     [refreshControl beginRefreshing];
     tableView.contentOffset = offset;

  }
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   if(refreshControl.isRefreshing) {
     yTableViewOffset = tableView.contentOffset.y;
     [refreshControl endRefreshing];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply calling `endRefreshing` in `viewWillDisappear:` fixed all the issues for me.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];        
}
```

Doing the same thing in `viewWillAppear:` caused the refresh control to rotate strangely when pulling the table.

Comment: view will disappear doesn't get called when we put application in background and in this case loader gets stuck

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
refreshControl.endRefreshing()
```

in viewWillAppear, and this should work.

Answer (score 2):

I have just seen the same thing. What I ended up doing is endRefreshing on viewWillDisappear and that at least eliminates this problem. 
However, coming back to the tab I expect it to start spinning again as I restart the refresh process and and call beginRefreshing again, but it does not. It does in the case when I drill down navigation and then come back though.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I can help solving this issue finally :

There is an issue using UITableView with a Pull-To-Refresh control.
This can be EASILY solved, by adding a UITableViewController.

```
UITableViewController *tableController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    tableController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    [tableController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:tableController];
    tableController.tableView = self.containerTableView;
    tableController.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;
```

This way you just wrap your UITableView inside a controller for which the `[self.refreshControl endRefreshing]` will work completely fine inside `viewWillAppear` or `viewWillDisappear`. In some cases you might need to call it in both.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Nicest fix in Swift:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)

  //fixes bug with refreshControl freezing while switching tabs
  if tableView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
    tableView.contentOffset = .zero
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While refresh control is spinning, if you present some other controller and come back before "end refreshing"; refresh animation will be stuck.

None of the answers above worked for me, and I didn't want to set bool and follow it through all lifecycle of a view controller.

My solution is adding below code to end of viewWillAppear.

in Objc;

```
if (self.refreshControl.isRefreshing) {
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y-self.refreshControl.frame.size.height) animated: true];
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
}
```

in Swift;

```
if self.refreshControl.isRefreshing {
     self.refreshControl.endRefreshing
     self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.contentOffset.y-self.refreshControl.frame.size.height), animated: true)
     self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing;
}
```

Logic is; whenever it catches refresh control is in the state of animating, it will stop it without knowing it is stuck or not and re-run the animation.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just add Below code and it works perfectly in all the conditions.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    guard refreshControl.isRefreshing else { return }
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
    tableView?.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -(refreshControl.bounds.height))
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, Important part was setting contentOffset.

Answer (score 0):

I have a collectionView, and I did set it's contentInset.

When pushing some ViewControllers, then press home button, and go back and pop back, the UIRefreshControl is always on the top.

Finally I use this code temporarily avoid it. (Ugly but stops it always shows on top)

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

    CGPoint currentContentOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset;

    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(currentContentOffset.x,
                                                      currentContentOffset.y - 1.0f)
                                 animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CGPoint currentContentOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset;

    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(currentContentOffset.x,
                                                      currentContentOffset.y + 1.0f)
                                 animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want some points and like Albert solution but not his style.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    _table.contentOffset = CGPointMake(_table.contentOffset.x, _table.contentOffset.y + 1.0f);
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    _table.contentOffset = CGPointMake(_table.contentOffset.x, _table.contentOffset.y - 1.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the call to endRefreshing to work before the navigation happened so I approached the problem from the other end and on viewWillAppear I check if the tableView contentOffset is a negative number bring the tableView back to 0.

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y < 0)
    {
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758892/uirefreshcontrol-stops-spinning-after-making-application-inactive) solved my problem

basically stopping and starting the spinner again on viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by placing the following piece of code in viewWillDisappear

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
```

If the above code is placed in viewWillAppear then spinner will animate and dismiss within a fraction of seconds, in either of the cases the issue will be solved but however, in users point of view the spinner should not be visible so, it's better to place it in viewWillDisappear.

Answer (score 0):

### Details

- Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8), Swift 5

### Problem

- Switching between tabs will freeze activity indicator
- `refreshControl.beginRefreshing(); refreshControl.endRefreshing()` - will send one more request/ pull to refresh event

### Solution

```
refreshControl.removeTarget(actionTarget, action: selector, for: .valueChanged)
refreshControl.endRefreshing()
refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
refreshControl.addTarget(actionTarget, action: actionSelector, for: .valueChanged)
```

### Full solution and sample

[How to use pull to refresh in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56794466/4488252)

Answer (score -1):

After running into the same problem several times I decided to make a library for it [SwiftPullToRefresh](https://github.com/Rep2/SwiftPullToRefresh/edit/master/README.md).

As said before, `refreshControl` needs to be stoped on `viewDidDisappear(_:)` and started on `viewWillAppear(_:)`.

When programatically starting `refreshControl` animation, `tableView.contentOffset` needs to be set to appropriate value.

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -(refreshControl?.bounds.height ?? 60) - topOffset), animated: true)

var topOffset: CGFloat {
    if let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar, navigationBar.isTranslucent == true {
        return navigationBar.bounds.height + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```