# UIRefreshControl Stuck After Switching Tabs in UITabBarController with UIViewControler and UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uirefreshcontrol

[image]My `UIRefreshControl` is stuck after switching tabs, It happenes only on the first tab. Inside TabBar I have 2 tabs with UIViewControler inside which I have UITableView.

I have tried all solutions suggested [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341192/uirefreshcontrol-stuck-after-switching-tabs-in-uitabbarcontroller) and none worked for me.

Below is what I am am doing.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[DataCache sharedCache] getData]];

[self addNavBar];
[self addDataTable];

//for refreshing the table data
UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
tableViewController.tableView = dataTable;
refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[refreshControl addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(refresh)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[dataTable addSubview:refreshControl];
tableViewController.refreshControl = refreshControl;
}


- (void)refresh {
[self loadSentData];
data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[DataCache sharedCache] getSentData]];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)reloadData{
[dataTable reloadData];
[refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

Comment: What is the desired behaviour? Will it stuck there and never disappear?

Comment: Usual behavior is `tableview`(dataTable) goes back up, to the same position and the `refreshView` goes away. This is also the desired behavior.

Comment: So it stuck there and never goes away?

Comment: Initially it works fine, But after I go to tab 2 and refresh data there and come back to tab1 and refresh data, Tab 1 is stuck at a position, its not going all the way back up to top. I can pull it down again, but It does not refreshes data and is stuck at that position with `UIRefreshControl` visible in the background, I have added a picture of the stuck area

Comment: Not sure what is the problem is. When it is stuck, does `reloadData` get called?

Comment: `reloadData` is not being called after its stuck. Though `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being called every time,  If that helps.

Comment: I have fixed this issue. In case someone is still stuck tet me know and I can share what worked for me.

Comment: @user1324887 I have something similar. If UIRefreshControl is animating during a transition to another screen, it's stuck when you return. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @ArtemStepanenko In my case, it was due to `refreshControl `. you need separate `refreshControl ` for both the views. I ended up creating `refreshControlFirstView` and `refreshControlSecondView` and that resolved the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question has been viewed hundreds of time. Adding my solution here might help someone else.

In my case, it was due to `refreshControl`. you need separate `refreshControl` for both the views. I ended up creating `refreshControlFirstView` and `refreshControlSecondView` and that resolved the issues.