# Pull to refresh plugin that works with hiding navigation bar when scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

There is a bug in IOS 9 for UIRefreshControl that when the refresher is animating and the user switches tabs, the refresher freezes when the user switches back. So I am trying to find a pull to refresh plugin that would work along side with hiding navigation bar when scrolling up. I have searched several places and could not find one that suits. Most of the ones out there will have weird behaviour when the navigation bar is hidden and the activity indicator animation stops animating. Can anyone recommend a good one?
[UIRefreshControl Stuck After Switching Tabs in UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341192/uirefreshcontrol-stuck-after-switching-tabs-in-uitabbarcontroller)

Here is how I hide navigation bar

```
self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://github.com/mengzhihoing/iOS-scroll-hide-navigationBar

Comment: No, my navigation bar can hide easy without plugin. It is the pull to refresh that is mainly causing me dramas as most of them only works properly when the navigation bar is static